# Wrong numeric suffix using GNU split

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, gnu, gnu-coreutils

I have a large (1.8GB) file, that I want to split in files of 100MB max. For this I am using the GNU split function, with option -d. The resulting numeric suffixes are weird. Until 89, all good, but then it starts from 9000, then 9001, ... and so on. Does anybody have an idea why I am getting this weird behavior?

Comment: What's the exact command you use? And what files exist in the directory already?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. Created a text file with 100000 lines and split it with `split -d -l 1000 delme.txt delme_` and this creates the files `delme_00` through `delme_89` and `delme_9000` through `delme_9009`. split version is 8.25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior of `split` might be unexpected, but it is [intended this way](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20874).

In order to create an arbitrary number of files while maintaining the correct lexical order, the suffix generator expands the number of digits when it reaches the highest digit possible in its first location.

The lexical order is necessary to easily reverse the split using cat:

```
split foo bar_
cat bar_* > foo
```

If lexical order were not maintained, the new `foo` would be jumbled up.

To achieve continuous numbers as the suffix, you can add the `-a <n>` argument, where `<n>` is the number of digits.

The following command will produce files `foo_000` through `foo_199`:

```
seq 20000 | split -d -a 3 -l 100 - foo_
```

However, then it is up to you to choose a number of digits sufficiently large to be able to generate all the suffixes you need, otherwise the `split` command will terminate prematurely with the error message:

```
split: output file suffixes exhausted
```

The issue has since been included in GNU coreutils [gotchas](https://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/coreutils-gotchas.html#split) page